# Samsung Galaxy : prevent browser to open phone app when clicking a number

Tags: android, galaxy

I got an app with phoneGap.

When the user click on some number (a price) in a normal `<span><b>` tag (no href, tel:, ...), the native phone application open.

How can I prevent this behavior? (ie: do nothing)

I made some search on various place, but nothing came out.

Comment: So you want the phonegap app to open up the the number instead of the native dialler? or you want your own personal app to open when a phone number is clicked?

Comment: If you are talking about web development and not wanting the number to be clickable, I suggest you direct your question toward web developers also.  However I believe only numbers with "tel:" in the html were clickable to call.

Comment: I edit my question to clarify. "I suggest you direct your question toward web developers" How do you suggest I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the solution was simple:

```
<meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
```

(same as iPhone...)